# Chakra Ui Number input is getting cut off

Tags: reactjs, input, frontend, numbers, chakra-ui

When trying to use the number input field in chakra ui  the right end of the text is always cutoff towards the end

```
<NumberInput width={16} size={'xs'} >

<NumberInputField />

</NumberInput>
```

[image]

In the case of the image above i typed 3232 into the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update I got this fixed by adding padding to the number input field manually.